# Problems with Partitions After Remove Windows

Tags: partitioning

I've recently removed the Windows partition  keeping Ubuntu as single OS. The way I did it was through an Ubuntu Live boot-drive, using the **Try Ubuntu** option. In `Gparted` I simply removed the referred partition. This is what `Gparted` shows:

```
/dev/sda1..fat16....39.19 MiB

unnallocated..unnallocated..281.78 GiB

/dev/sda4..(KEY)..extended..183.94 GiB

../dev/sda6..ext4..180.03 GiB

../dev/sda5..(KEY)..linux-swap..3.91 GiB

unnallocated..unnallocated..1.02 MiB
```

My problem is that I can not expand my `ext4` partition. My goal is to make the unallocated space usable. Can anyone help me?

I would like to clean up this partitions too, keeping just what I use.

Comment: You will get a better output if you type `sudo parted -l` into a terminal window and post that output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/dev/sda6` partition is a logical volume inside the extended partition `/dev/sda4`.

Extended partitions are like containers. They are needed, because there are (were?) only 4 primary partitions allowed at one disk. So somebody invented the extended partition, that can replace one primary partition and contain any number of logical partitions inside.

So now the reason why you can not enlarge sda6 is, that the container sda4 is full. You have to enlarge the extended partition first (therefore you might have to unmount all containing volumes (sda5 and sda6) and the extended partition itself (sda4)). Then, when you have free space *inside* the container, you can enlarge the partitions *inside* the container, to cover that new space.

Do you need more explanations or could I help you?

Comment: *Are* on MBR partitioned drives, *were* on GPT partitioned drives.  ;-)  (And an upvote!)